# 100% Div height without scrollbar

Tags: css, html

I have a two column layout:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="sidewrapper"></div>
        <div id="contentwrapper"></div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to have both sidebar and content be 100% in height but the most top container's min-height should be 100%.

I tried to solve it with the following css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    color: #000; height:100%; min-height:100px;
}

body {
    background: #fff; height:100%; min-height:100px; overflow:hidden;   
}

#header {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
float: left;
height: 23px;
}

#container {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%; height:100%;
    margin: auto; background:blue;
}

#contentwrapper {
    float:left;
    background:red;
    position: relative;
    width: 700px; padding:0px; margin:0px;
    height: auto; 
}

#sidewrapper {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 159px; height:100%; 
    padding:0px; margin:0px;
}
```

...but I get a scrollbar because of the header's 23px height. I tried to solve it with overflow:hidden for the body element but I do not know if that is the right solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are some mistakes in your demo code. I guess #sidewrapper is actually #sidebar, and #contentwrapper is actually #content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If my assumption I put forward in my comment to the question is right, then `sidebar` is `100%` high, and on top of that you have a `23px` header, so that causs  your container to be `100%` + `23px` high.

In the future you will have in css `calc()` http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/css3-calc/ . This will solve your problem.

Now, I guess you should calculate the height of the sidebar ( = height of container - 23px), by javascript.

Comment: Be aware that `calc()` won't work on all browsers and that Javascript can be disabled.

Comment: Actually the calc() thing is a CSS thing, and won't work on almost no browser.

Comment: The JS option I suggest, will not work on browsers without javascript, but than again: these people are used to sites not looking at their best because they have no javascript. The 23px scrollbar will be the least of their annoyances.

Answer (score 6):

Make `#header` position absolute. This will cut that block out of the normal flow and you'll be able to make heights of other blocks equal to their parent.

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height: 23px;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
#sidewrapper,
#contentwrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
#sidewrapper .content,
#contentwrapper .content {
    margin-top: 23px;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I set the header to a specific height and set the margin-top of the content wrapper to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

The height of an element is compared with its father element. In your case, I recommend you specify the concrete width & height for "containter", because it'll be hard to pretend the size of the screen on many machines.

If you insists use percent, I recommend you use for both element, such as header 25% height and content 75% height.

Comment: Often the exact header size is known, (often a menu or something like that). So you don't want to give the header a variable height.

Comment: Yes, because of that I recommend you to use the concrete values for the root elements (container,header in your case), such as 1024x800, 23x800 or so. Then use percentage values inside.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say I've a html body and a div inside and I want to make the height of the div to the entire browser without scroll bar and side gaps. Then understand the following example below, and implement your own.

Html:

```
<body>
<div id="yellowDiv">
<div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
margin:0px;
}

yellowDiv{
background-color:yellow;
height:100vh;
}
```