# Extend 2 divs to bottom of page

Tags: css, html, extend

I've been struggling with this one for hours and have tried everything I can think of/find to get this to work. I want the content and sidebar divs of my website to extend down to the sticky footer.

relating css:

```
body, html {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;    
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    }

body { 
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 21px;
    background: #e0d6b6 url(images/bg.png) repeat-x;
    color: #2f2f2f;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
    }

.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 0 auto -30px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

.contentwrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 5%;
    }

#content,
#sidebar {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    }

#content {
    min-width: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 0 auto 0;
}

#sidebar {
    margin: 0 0 auto 2% !important;
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
    }

.footer, .push {
    clear: both;
    height: 30px;
    }

#footer {
    display: block;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 12px;    
    border: none;
    background: #808080;
    color: #c4c4c4;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

relating html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="contentwrapper">
<div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
<div id="content">    
content
</div><!--content-->
</div><!--contentwrapper-->
<div id="push"></div>
<div id="footer">
footer
</div> <!--footer-->
</div><!--container-->
</body>
</html>
```

The website is http://hoskyns50.co.uk if you want to see the raw code. I'm adapting an existing Wordpress layout to suit. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `height: auto !important;` on your `.contentwrapper`

because what you want is `height: 100%;`. Your `height: auto !important;` is overriding your `height: 100%;`.

**Edit**

To fix your footer problem

Change your position on `#footer` to

```
position: fixed;
```

instead of

```
position: relative;
```

But I'm not sure if this is what you want, because not the footer will follow your scroll.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xHJA4/

Comment: thank you so much! Argh can't believe it was that simple.

It does mess up my footer slightly though, any idea how I can get that to sticky at the bottom again?

Comment: @user2561163 I edited my answer for an attempt to fix your footer. :)

Comment: I'd rather not have the footer always visible, like a menu, in fixed position...but thanks anyway

I now have the problem that the content div is not always big enough to extend with the text and creates a scrollbar. If I set

    overflow: hidden;

then the content is not always visible past a certain point.

Comment: You don't want the scroll bar?

Comment: No scrollbar, I'd like the content to extend the whole page like this website does.

Comment: I fixed the footer problem by adjusting the push setting but would really like to solve the content scrollbar issue.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274914/100-div-height-without-scrollbar

Comment: I think you should ask a separate question for this. Someone else might be able to help you.